# Individually accessing the points of scatter points in BQPLOT

Tags: bqplot

I would like to change the size of a point amongst scatter points in BQPLOT. What is the best way to do it without affecting the size of the rest of the points?

Thanks

Comment: You can link the size up to a scale and change the values that way. See example in this notebook about halfway down. https://github.com/bqplot/bqplot/blob/master/examples/Marks/Object%20Model/Scatter.ipynb

Comment: I see, it is not related to the scale actually. It is more about the size array but thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved it, I am leaving this here in case it can help somebody.
I go about it using a size array:

```
    size_r = np.array([0.1,0.5,0.5, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.8,0.5])
    scat = bplt.scatter(x,y,size = size_r)
```

The issue is that the smallest marker (of size 0.1 in this case) will not appear. I go about it by adding a dummy scatter point at the beginning of my data, and I give it the smallest number of the size array (it can be 0 for example).